# How to calculate the probability density function of X+Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume we have $
f_{X}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{4}(1-x^2), &\text{if } -1\leq x\leq 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$ and  $
f_{Y}(y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3} &\text{if } 0<y<1 \\
\frac{2}{3} &\text{if } 2<y<3 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$ and I want to calculate the probability density function of $Z=X+Y$ ($X,Y$ are independent).

We know that if $X,Y$ are continuous, then we have:

$f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(z-y)f_{Y}(y)dy$

Can we use this here too? if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

$f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(z-y)f_{Y}(y)dy$
$=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{3}f_{X}(z-y)dy + \int_{2}^{3} \frac{2}{3}f_{X}(z-y)dy$

The first term can be calculated as

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{3}f_{X}(z-y)dy = \int_{z-1}^{z} \frac{1}{3}f_X(u)du = \int_{z-1}^{z} \frac{1}{4}(1-u^2)1_{-1 \leq u \leq 1}du  = \frac{1}{4}(u-\frac{1}{3}u^3)\Large{|}_{\max(-1, z-1)}^{\min(1, z)}$

We can see that the important intervals here are $z \in [-1, 0]$ and $z \in [0, 2]$. You can do similarly for the other term.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have one other question. In other to calculate $\int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(z-y)dy$, can we use this: $u=z-y$ so $du=-dy$?

Comment: I mean, what are these intervals for? z or y? could you please calculate one of these intervals?

Comment: Yes to your first question. I have rewritten my answer in a way that hopefully makes it clearer where the intervals are coming from and what they are. I have also calculated the first term for you.